# Find, Merge, then delete rows containing some duplicate columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an MSSQL table that looks like this:

```
ID    |  name    |  surname    |  data1    | data2   | data3
1     |  John    |  Doe        |  jdata1   | jdata2  | null
1     |  John    |  Doe        |  jdata1   | null    | jdata3
2     |  Jane    |  Dame       |  jane1    | null    | jane3
3     |  Jack    |  Horner     |  jack1    | jack2   | null
3     |  Jack    |  Horner     |  jack1    | jack2   | jack3
3     |  Jack    |  Horner     |  jack1    | jack2   | jack3
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
ID    |  name    |  surname    |  data1    | data2   | data3
1     |  John    |  Doe        |  jdata1   | jdata2  | jdata3
2     |  Jane    |  Dame       |  jane1    | null    | jane3
3     |  Jack    |  Horner     |  jack1    | jack2   | jack3
```

The DB is a bit of a mess - import from a csv file, and basically, each record seems to be duplicated, with only one or two columns being different - ie, first row will have null, and second row will have a value in that column.

To complicate things, some records have only one row, and others have three entries, where two of the three related rows are identical and the other row exhibiting the "swapped" columns as described earlier.

In total about 44m rows that I am trying to detect and merge - iow, fill in the null values with the columns from the duplicate rows, and then delete the duplicate, non complete rows so there is always only one row per ID number.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an aggregation:

```
select id, name, surname,
       max(data1) as data1, max(data2) as data2, max(data3) as data3
from table t
group by id, name, surname;
```

Note that if there are multiple values in one of the data columns, only one will be chosen.  (There are no examples of this in your sample data.)

EDIT:

If you want to change the table itself, I would suggest storing the results in a temporary table and re-inserting the data:

```
select id, name, surname,
       max(data1) as data1, max(data2) as data2, max(data3) as data3
into #tmp
from table t
group by id, name, surname;

truncate table t;

insert into t(id, name, surname, data1, data2, data3)
    select id, name, surname, data1, data2, data
    from table t;
```

However, it is easier probably just to keep the original table and use a query/view to extract the data in the right format.

Comment: @Monty asks to update the table with values of other rows, so this select statement won't be of much help then..

Comment: No, this solution is fine. It allows you to save the aggregated values to a temporary table and compare to the original values before replacing them. There are numerous advantages in doing so.

Comment: @NickyvV . . . I find the intent of the OP a bit ambiguous about whether the table *really* has to be changed or whether the data just has to be combined the right way.  In any case, it is easy enough to adapt the code to repopulate the table.